# How can I get virtual host to work with XAMPP?

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I just reinstalled XAMPP on my Win 7 machine yesterday. I am working on a Laravel project. I installed the current version of Laravel and then I went to set up the virtual host on the local machine. When I go to the url I set up (jrd_dnd_tools.localhost) I get a Bad Gateway message If I go to localhost I get the site the url is supposed to go to. I've set up virtual hosts before but no idea why this is happening. I'm sure I am missing something stupid but can't figure out what.

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@jrd_dnd_tools.localhost
     DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Joey\Web\jrd_dnd_tools/public"
     ServerName jrd_dnd_tools.localhost
     ServerAlias www.jrd_dnd_tools.localhost
     ErrorLog "logs/jrd_dnd_tools.localhost.log"
     CustomLog "logs/jrd_dnd_tools.localhost.log" common
     <Directory "C:\Users\Joey\Web\jrd_dnd_tools/public">
          AllowOverride All
          Order Allow,Deny
          Allow from all

          ## --New way of doing it
          Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
::1             database.localhost
127.0.0.1       jrd_dnd_tools.localhost
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows)

Comment: I know it looks like a possible duplicate but I have searched Stack Exchange and Google and haven't found an answer that seems to fix the problem

Comment: `C:\Users\Joey\Web\jrd_dnd_tools/public` - you are mixing forward- and back-slashes, for both `DocumentRoot` and  `<Directory>`. Not sure if that would cause "bad gateway" but it is certainly wrong - try fixing to all backslashes.

Comment: Also check your error log for any more details.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy check your browser configuration and feed "no use proxy for..." with the local names you need to use (and add the www... alias to your hosts file too).

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no I haven't

Answer (score 1):

What you have mistaken is `*:80`, for virtual hosts never use wildcards. Instead you can do `jrd_dnd_tools.localhost`. Here below is my virtual host setup, I did for demo.

And also notice directory separators I have in Document Root and directory.

Make these 2 changes and your virtual host will work like a charm.

```
<VirtualHost t.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@t.com
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/t"
     ServerName t.com
     ServerAlias t.com
     ## ErrorLog "logs/jrd_dnd_tools.localhost.log"
     ##CustomLog "logs/jrd_dnd_tools.localhost.log" common
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/t">
          AllowOverride All
          Order Allow,Deny
          Allow from all

          ## --New way of doing it
          Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I set it up like this but now I am getting a bad request error.

Comment: @JoeyD473 - I hope you have also made a change in `.hosts` file. Like `127.0.0.1       t.com`.

Comment: My hosts file is the same as in the original file